# How to use properties from Metrowindow above framed page

Tags: c#, wpf, mahapps.metro

Using Mahapps.metro, and stumbling into a problem.

I want to page paged content, all controlled via a frame within metro window.

There are two things I cannot figure out how to do, which was easy enough whilst working all within one window without the pages.

First off, I want to use their dialogs. The following line worked previousely whilst used directly within the window:

```
await this.ShowMessageAsync("This is the title", "User Setting: " + x);
```

However, it now gives the following error:

> Instance argument: cannot convert from 'GameWindow.MainMenu' to 'MahApps.Metro.Controls.MetroWindow'

I have tried searching for an answer, as well as trying things such as

```
await this.Parent.ShowMessageAsync("This is the title", "User Setting: " + x);
```

but all to no avail.

Secondly, I have a flyout configured in my window, which I need to access from a page within the frame also. I cannot for the life of me figure this one out either...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to walk up the visual tree to find the `MetroWindow` instance, e.g.

```
using MahApps.Metro.Controls;
using MahApps.Metro.Controls.Dialogs;

await this.TryFindParent<MetroWindow>()
    .ShowMessageAsync("This is the title", "User Setting: " + x);
```

`TryFindParent<>` is an extension method defined in `MahApps.Metro.Controls.TreeHelper`, and `ShowMessageAsync<>` is defined in `MahApps.Metro.Controls.Dialogs.DialogManager`. If you don't want to use extension methods, try this code:

```
var window = TreeHelper.TryFindParent<MetroWindow>(this);
await DialogManager.ShowMessageAsync(window, "This is the title", "User Setting: " + x);
```

Comment: Hi Thomas, I can't get that to work. When I use that, I get this error message: 'GameWindow.MainMenu' does not contain a definition for 'TryFindParent' and no extension method 'TryFindParent' accepting a first argument of type 'GameWindow.MainMenu' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Have you added `using MahApps.Metro.Controls;` to your source file?

Comment: You can also call `MahApps.Metro.Controls.TreeHelper.TryFindParent<MetroWindow>(this)...`

Comment: I am now seeing: 'MahApps.Metro.Controls.MetroWindow' does not contain a definition for 'ShowMessageAsync' and no extension method 'ShowMessageAsync' accepting a first argument of type 'MahApps.Metro.Controls.MetroWindow' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I have tried calling a few different methods by replacing ShowMessageAsync with a method written within the game window but no joy still (they were public).

Comment: `ShowMessageAsync` is an extension method defined in `MahApps.Metro.Controls.Dialogs.DialogManager`. I edited my original answer to show both ways, with and without extension methods.

Comment: Using code:
            var window = TreeHelper.TryFindParent<MetroWindow>(this);
            await DialogManager.ShowMessageAsync(window, "This is the title", "User Setting: ");

Gives me the error message:
The name 'DialogManager' does not exist in the current context

And nothing is seeming to work... I have both using statements in also...

Comment: `DialogManager` is in namespace `MahApps.Metro.Controls.Dialogs` for ages. Which version of MahApps.Metro are you using?

Comment: 1.1.2.0 - Released yesterday I believe? Was originally using 1.1.1.0 though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72065/discussion-between-thomas-freudenberg-and-matthew-parker).