# ShowInputAsync is not showed sometimes

Tags: wpf, modal-dialog, mahapps.metro

I realized an interface in WPF `Page` and I want to call `ShowInputAsync` in the `MainWindow`, which is where the `Page` is. In order to do that, I raise event in `Page` and block function with `AutoResetEvent`:

```
public AutoResetEvent OnMessageReceived;

public void MessageReceived(object sender, PageReturnMessageEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (e.ToString() == "Cancel" || string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.ToString()))
        {
            throw new Exception("Exception of parsing of hours");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // log it
    }
    this.OnMessageReceived.Set();
}

private void Page_OnNextPageClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // ...

    MessageShow("Additional information", "How much time will this SuperProcess take?", "HOURS");

    OnMessageReceived.WaitOne();
    OnMessageReceived.Reset();

    // ...
}
```

If I try to show `ShowInputAsync` from any function in `MainWindow` it works:

```
MetroDialogSettings s = new MetroDialogSettings();
s.AffirmativeButtonText = @"Create";
s.NegativeButtonText = @"Cancel";
s.AnimateShow = true;
var result = await this.ShowInputAsync("Test", "TestMessage", s);

if (result == null)
{ return; }
```

[image: Image of the dialog]

If I try to show this dialog from event handler, it doesn't work. After line

```
var result = await this.ShowInputAsync("Test", "TestMessage", s);
```

code returns to `Page` without any exception, executes line

```
OnMessageReceived.WaitOne();
```

and shows the window without any dialog, all `Control`s are showing and enabled, but I can't press them.

I also tried to put the dialog in a separate function, and call it with/without `await`, nothing changes.

To use `AutoResetEvent` after calling the `Dialog` to block further execution of code, also didn't help.

```
private AutoResetEvent OnMessageReturning;
var result = await this.ShowInputAsync(e.Title, e.Message, s);
OnMessageReturning.WaitOne();
```

Also tried to call the separate function in this way without result:

```
CancellationToken token;
TaskScheduler uiSched = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
await Task.Factory.StartNew(SeparateFunction, token, TaskCreationOptions.None, uiSched);
```

How can I call ShowInputAsync correctly in event handler? Or how can I call `ShowInputAsync` from `Page` in `MainWindow`?

P.S. There is `TabControl` in `MainWindow`, `Page` is placed in `Frame` of one `TabItem`

Using:

- MahApps.Metro v1.4.1 (NuGet package)
- Windows OS 7
- Visual Studio Express 2015
- .NET Framework 4.5

**UPD**: Easy sample is https://github.com/awg21/MahAppsShowInputAsyncFromPage

Comment: I uploaded on GitHub, link is above, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28799317/2528269) I'm using:

> TryFindParent<> is an extension method defined in MahApps.Metro.Controls.TreeHelper, and ShowMessageAsync<> is defined in MahApps.Metro.Controls.Dialogs.DialogManager